# Исправить реализацию метода заметающей прямой

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Вечер добрый, пользователи Стэка.
Я пишу специфическую реализацию метода заметающей прямой, (скорее даже общей концепции метода), и когда уже почти всё готово, получил проблему, с которой никак не могу справиться..
*Каждый раз, когда я обновляю активный набор отрезков, все, кроме последнего удаляются.*
Теперь чуть подробнее:
Задача состоит в том, чтобы соединить отрезки в контуры, если их конечные точки совпадают. 
Метод заметающей прямой заключается в том, что некая прямая как сканером проходит по отрезкам, и анализирует не всё сразу, а только те отрезки, которые в данный момент пересекает. Ключевыми моментами для этого алгоритма является точка начала отрезка, и точка конца, так как именно в них прямая пересекает отрезок, или выходит из его области. Есть две коллекции - очередь приоритетов и активный набор, очередь приоритетов не меняется, а активный набор зависит от того, какие отрезки в данный момент "разрезаны" заметающей прямой. Отрезки в активный набор постоянно добавляются и удаляются, и видно, я где-то допустил ошибку в этом механизме..
[Можно посмотреть тот же код на Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/S7ACnnnJ) или [Полный код проекта тут](https://teaowl@bitbucket.org/teaowl/outlinealgorithm.git)
Вычитал о заметающей прямой [тут](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/intersecting_segments#2), и когда половину не понял, пользовался [этой](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/line-sweep-algorithms/) статьей (второй абзац).
p.s. в статьях везде речь именно о пересечении отрезков, а не о соединении конечных точек, но главное - принцип..
p.p.s. небольшая иллюстрация:
[image: небольшая иллюстрация]

```
using SegmentsAlgorythm;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OutlineAlgorithm
{
    public class NewOutlineProcessor
    {
        private List<Outline> outlines = new List<Outline>();

        private List<Segment> prioritySet = new List<Segment>();

        private EventComparator eventComparator = new EventComparator();
        private ByStartComparator byStartComparator = new ByStartComparator();

        public async Task addElement(Segment segment)
        {
            prioritySet.Add(segment);
            //перераспределяем отрезки на числовой прямой
            //p.s.Встроенные алгоритмы отлично оптимизированы - почти отсортированный массив пересортируется очень быстро
            //p.p.s.как ни велик соблазн положить сортировку в отдельный поток, без синхронизации нельзя
            prioritySet.Sort(byStartComparator);
            await FindOutline();
            Console.WriteLine("---Priority Set---");
            foreach (Segment seg in prioritySet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(seg);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("---Result Set---");
            foreach (Outline outline in outlines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(outline);
            }

        }

        private Task FindOutline()
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                List<SweepLineEvent> activeSet = new List<SweepLineEvent>();
                //обыскивать активный набор
                foreach (Segment segment in prioritySet)
                {   
                    //добавление события - хороший момент для анализа, как и удаление
                    SweepLineEvent segmentStartEvent;
                    segmentStartEvent.POI = segment.start;
                    segmentStartEvent.parent = segment;
                    segmentStartEvent.TYPE = SweepLineEvent.START;

                    SweepLineEvent segmentEndEvent;
                    segmentEndEvent.POI = segment.end;
                    segmentEndEvent.parent = segment;
                    segmentEndEvent.TYPE = SweepLineEvent.END;

                    activeSet.Add(segmentEndEvent);
                    activeSet.Add(segmentStartEvent);
                    activeSet.Sort(eventComparator);
                    Console.WriteLine("---Active Set---");
                    foreach (SweepLineEvent seg in activeSet)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(seg);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("---Sweep line cycle---");
                    for (int i = 0; i < activeSet.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < activeSet.Count; j++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Count = "+ activeSet.Count);
                            Console.WriteLine("Точка интереса " + activeSet[i].POI + " рассматривается..");
                            if (Math.Abs(activeSet[i].POI.X - activeSet[j].POI.X) < 0.001f && i>1)
                            {
                                //если равен х, то равен и у
                                if (activeSet[i].POI.Y == activeSet[j].POI.Y)
                                {
                                    AddOutline(activeSet[i].parent, activeSet[j].parent);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Новый контур обрабатывается..");
                                }
                            }
                            //если это конец отрезка, значит, он ушёл из зоны видимости, ведь все события отсортированы
                            //p.s. последний не считается - ситуация может изменится на следующей итерации
                            bool isTheEnd = activeSet[i].TYPE == SweepLineEvent.END;
                            if (isTheEnd && i!=activeSet.Count-1)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Заметающая прямая больше не пересекает отрезок " + activeSet[i].parent);
                                activeSet.RemoveAll(e => e.parent.Equals(activeSet[i].parent));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void AddOutline(Segment segment, Segment foundedSegment)

        {
            //исследование в уже существующем контуре
            Console.WriteLine("---исследование в уже существующем контуре---");
            Outline first = searchInOtherOutlines(segment);
            Outline second = searchInOtherOutlines(foundedSegment);
            //если отрезки состоят в одном и том же непустом контуре, значит, ничего делать не нужно
            if (first != null && first == second)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Контур уже существует");
                return;
            }
                //первый есть..
                if (first != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("отрезок " + segment + " уже есть в контурах..");
                //..а второго нет(наиболее распространённая ситуация)
                if (second == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("а отрезка " + foundedSegment + " в контурах ещё нет, добавляем...");
                    first.Add(foundedSegment);
                    Console.WriteLine("итоговый контур: " + first);
                }
                else
                {
                    //..или и второй есть
                    Console.WriteLine("отрезок " + foundedSegment + " тоже..");
                    Console.WriteLine("оба есть в контурах! ");
                    Console.WriteLine("все проверки считаются проваленными...");
                }
            }
            //..или нет первого
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("отрезка " + segment + " нет в контурах..");
                //..но есть второй..
                if (second != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("но " + foundedSegment + " есть, добавим первый к нему..");
                    second.Add(segment);
                    Console.WriteLine("итоговый контур " + second);
                }
                //..или обоих нет
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("отрезка " + foundedSegment + " тоже");
                    Outline newOutline = new Outline(segment, foundedSegment);
                    outlines.Add(newOutline);
                    Console.WriteLine("так как совпадение всё же обнаружено, создаётся новый контур: " + newOutline);
                }
            }
        }

        private Outline searchInOtherOutlines(Segment segment)
        {
            Outline found = null;
            foreach (Outline outline in outlines)
            {
                if (outline.Contains(segment)) found = outline;
            }
            return found;
        }

        private class ByStartComparator : IComparer<Segment>
        {
            public int Compare(Segment first, Segment second)
            {
                return first.start.X.CompareTo(second.start.X);
            }
        }

        private class EventComparator : IComparer<SweepLineEvent>
        {
            public int Compare(SweepLineEvent first, SweepLineEvent second)
            {
                return first.POI.X.CompareTo(second.POI.X);
            }
        }

        private struct SweepLineEvent
        {
            public string TYPE;
            public const string START = "START";
            public const string END = "END";
            public PointF POI; //point of interest
            public Segment parent;

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "["+TYPE + " | " + POI + " | Parent:" + parent+"]";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: /Решение найдено, но немного костыльное, так что предложения всё ещё принимаются/